# path problem when using sub directories

Tags: html, filepath

I am working on a site where i have arranged my pages in directories except for the index page. My problem occurs when i use jquery to append images to a div within a section of the pages. It shows on the index page but not on other pages (which are directories). I understand why but not sure how i can fix it.

Is there a way to fix this without having to remove my other files from directories?

```
var $img1 = $('<img src="images/test1.jpg" />');
var $img2 = $('<img src="images/test2.jpg" />');
$('#container').append($img1, $img2);
```

**Please note that the above code is also in a separate directory**

Comment: What does the xhtml tag have to do this question?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your `images` folder is located within the root directory of your website, you could just make the `src` attribute root-relative:

```
var $img1 = $('<img src="/images/test1.jpg" />');
var $img2 = $('<img src="/images/test2.jpg" />');
$('#container').append($img1, $img2);
```

(Note the `/` added to the beginning of the `src` attribute).

Reference:

- [Having links relative to root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559578/havling-links-relative-to-root/5559597#5559597) (Apologies for any percieved self-promotion, but it was the first Google result here on Stackoverflow for my search for "[root-relative url site:stackoverflow.com](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=root-relative+url+site%3Astackoverflow.com)").

Comment: yes it is but i tried that before posting the question and it did not work.

Comment: In what way did it 'not work'? It certainly ***should*** work. Is there any way you can provide a link to a demo site showing your attempts? Did you look at the console to see if there was a JavaScript error, or if the resources returned a 404 (or other) header?

Comment: there is no error. i have used firebug to inspect what is going on, and its simply is not loading the image. Perhaps, i should have pointed out that my js file is also in a sub-directory.

Comment: It doesn't matter from where your JS is loaded, since the `src` will be relative (unless you use an absolute path, obviously) to the file/document in which they're loaded.

Comment: your actually right, that comment does not make much sense. however, i'm not sure just / would work for files in sub-directories. Dont you have to do something like ../ to get to a level higher?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the full link including domain name:
 `var $img1 = $('<img src="http://www.yoursitename.com/images/test1.jpg" />');`

Comment: I know of the posibility to use absolute url but isn't there a way with relative path?

Comment: @gables20: Yes, you can use relative path from the root as David said. But in the case if your site is hosted in subfolder of e.g. your organization's site ( e.g `http://organization.com/yoursite/`), you should take into account that `/` refers to `http://organization.com/`, not `http://organization.com/yoursite/`. Look at the `<BASE>` html tag: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.4