# How to change window.location entire uri , w/o seting the entire url?

Tags: javascript

Assuming you have this url : http://www.domain.com////// . How is possible to change the uri path , by seting only the relative path (window.location = 'home') not the absolute one ( window.location = 'http://www.domain.com/home') . If you assing to location.href a relative path , the above url would be www.domain.com/////home . I want www.domain.com/home

Comment: It appears you want your links to be relative to the root. You should find an answer in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559578/havling-links-relative-to-root

Comment: @Jacob yea, true . Idk why i had the ideea the browsers will set the root w/o the seting the initial "/" .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
location.href = "/home"
```

Setting the URL to a string starting with "/" goes back to the "root" level, so right after the host address. Using "../" you can go back single levels, like navigating through a filesystem.