# How can I modify this javascript to ignore any data within a query string?

Tags: javascript, facebook, url, url-rewriting, facebook-like

Essentially, I have this website, the content of which changes depending on what the user inputs into the query string.

When the user enters mysite.com/?1 it loads content for 1 and /?2 for 2

My problem is that I have a Facebook like button within my page, and to make it work I have written this js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sUrl = window.location;
    document.getElementById('fbcom').setAttribute('href', sUrl);
</script>
```

this gets the url and allows the user to like different content from what is technically one file.

My problem is that when a user likes for example /?1 on facebook, if someone where to click this link on their newsfeed and decide that they like it too, technically they will be liking the page /?1-with all the additional facebook code on the end of the url, so heading back to /?1 the like has not registered.

How can I modify the above code to ignore any facebook rubbish on the end of the url when they are directed from facebook?

Important: the ID /?1 can be anything from a 1 digit to a 4 digit number e.g /?1234
My current JS ability is very poor. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that with regex:

```
var sUrl = window.location.toString().replace(/^(.*?)(\?.*)?$/, '$1');
```

Comment: I have used .htaccess file to rewrite the url from site.com/?1 to site.com/1 how would I implement this into the same example but without the question mark? sorry I don't really understand your code

Comment: hmmm.. my code is based on the `?`, it remove the part of the string that follows it!. what would this url for i.e. `http://domain.com/test.php?user=user&data=data` become after applying your .htaccess rewrite rules?

Comment: @user2228313 Note that JavaScript sees the URL as the browser sees it. If you're rewriting between `/?1` (query) server-side and `/1` (path) client-side, JavaScript will only know the `/1` (path). If instead the "query" variant is seen client-side, then the replace can be altered to look for an `&`, which should separate the `1` from any Facebook name/values.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the [properties of `location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location#Properties) you actually want to keep -- which seems to be `protocol`, `host`, and `pathname`:

```
var sLoc = window.location;
var sUrl = sLoc.protocol + '//' + sLoc.host + sLoc.pathname;
```

You can also just use the `pathname` as [relative-from-root](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5559578/):

```
var sUrl = window.location.pathname;
```