# forward from spring jsp to spring jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp

in catalog 
    `webapp/WEB-INF/views` located my jsp pages
I want to forward from 1.jsp to 2.jsp

in 1.jsp I write

```
<a href="2.jsp?id=${candidate.id}">${candidate.name}</a>
```

but it doesn't work.
How to fix it?

Comment: Are you trying to do an internal forward, or are you trying to create a link to the second page for the user to click on?

Comment: I am trying to create a link to the second page for the user to click on

Answer (score 0):

Use `<c:url` and then the `value` attribute of `<c:url` is set to the `href` link to the other JSP. So for example, it would be:

```
<a href="<c:url value="2.jsp?id=${candidate.id}" />">${candidate.name}</a>
```

I had used it in the following manner in my webapps (where circuits is a folder under `/WEB-INF/views`):

```
<a href="<c:url value="/circuits/${circuit.circuitId}/edit" />">Edit Circuit</a>
```

Comment: Done. If there are any problems, then please comment further.

Comment: HTTP Status 404 - /ui/2.jsp

Comment: I dont't watch differencies between my and your variants

Comment: Firstly, <c:url is the way to go, because otherwise you can't pass JSP parameters (${candidate.id}). If you are getting a 404 error, make sure that the JSP directory is correct and the name of the JSP.

Comment: JSP directory: webapp/WEB-INF/views

Comment: I copy name from details this jsp

Comment: You may want to have a look at the following: http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/simple-spring-web-flow-webapp-jsp-example.html

Comment: I think client can't access to webapp/WEB-INF/views

Comment: If you use c:URL then you should put the parameters in the param sub tags, but not in the value parameter! - anyway you are right: c:URL is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

A relative url should start with a `/` character

Change the anchor tag as below and try again

```
<a href="/2.jsp?id=${candidate.id}">${candidate.name}</a>
```

[Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559578/having-links-relative-to-root)

Comment: client can't access to webapp/WEB-INF/views

Comment: It is main problem. If I write right url in browser then I will see 404

Comment: @user2674303 By which url you are accessing 1.jsp, which contains the link to 2.jsp ?

Comment: link to 2.jsp it means