# How do I link back out of a folder using the a-href tag?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, directory

Alright so I have a page in a folder, the page is called jobs.html and the folder is simply called "jobs". Its a sub folder of my mine "website" folder. In the main directory of the "main" folder is my "home.html" file. When I try to do

```
<a href="home.html">bla</a>
```

It malfunctions as it is looking for the home file in the jobs folder, which does not exist.

So I ask, how can I reference out of a folder to call a file from the root folder?

Comment: `<a href="../home.html">bla</a>`

Comment: Has already been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559578/having-links-relative-to-root

Comment: b.t.w a way to make urls simple in you code is to have a server side constant which holdes the base url of your site (let say BASE_URL) then all your urls would be a. full and not relative) and B. simpler

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try setting your link to be your site root as so; note the `/` in front of `home.html`:

```
<a href="/home.html">bla</a>
```

Or if you know the path is definitely one directory down then just explicitly tell it to go down 1 directory; note the `../` in front of the `home.html`.

```
<a href="../home.html">bla</a>
```

Comment: For some reason putting the /home rather than ../home lead straight to my root directory on C:, which is strange. The double dots ended up working though.

Answer (score 2):

You can move up a directory by using `../` before your html document.  So if `home.html` is up one directory, you could do:

```
<a href="../home.html">bla</a>
```

Comment: Great, respect ++