# I can't link my html file to another html file

Tags: html

```
<a href="folder1/index.html">Home Page</a>
```

I used this instruction in my code to link another code in another folder but when I test and press Home Page it doesn't work !

Comment: How does your application folder structure look like? Maybe the path you are using is not correct. The link above should work

Comment: in my desktop i have a folder named myFolder containing two folders : folder1 (which contains index.html) and folder2 (which contains the file of this instruction's code)

Comment: does this work `<a href="./folder1/index.html">Home Page</a>`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I link back out of a folder using the a-href tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20599870/how-do-i-link-back-out-of-a-folder-using-the-a-href-tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is: `<a href="folder1/index.html">Home Page</a>`;

Lets understand what it does. This code must be in some file. Lets say you are double-clicking a file `myFile.html` and this code is written inside it.

Now, this line says that at the very same location you have got a folder named - `folder1` and inside it, there lies a file `index.html`. So, the structure would be like.

[image]

Now, if the `path is correct`, your file will open. There is nothing wrong in the code you have written.

**You got 2 folders, each have got 1 files**

Now, for your issue, first you need to go 1-space up and then go to the other folder. To go 1-place-up we use `../` instruction.

So, for you the answer would be:

`<a href="../folder1/index.html">Home Page</a>`

Comment: in my desktop i have a folder named myFolder containing two folders : folder1 (which contains index.html) and folder2 (which contains the file of this instruction's code)  ...
So how should the instruction be instead ?

Comment: @BacimOUESLATI - I've updated the answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your folder's name true or file path is true, if all of them is true try Home Page

Comment: <a href="./folder1/index.html">Home Page</a>

Answer (score 0):

based on the comments this is the folder structure you are using:

```
-myFolder
--folder1 (contains index.html)
--folder2 (contains the code you wrote)
```

to link from folder2 to folder1 you need to use `../` like this:

```
<a href="../folder1/index.html">Home Page</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

With your structure looking as this:

```html
myFolder
   |
   |----------folder1
                 |
                 |-----------> index.html
   |
   |----------folder2
                 |
                 |-----------> another_file.html
```

To link `index.html` from `another_file.html`, you need to carefully note the path from `folder2` to `folder1`. You will need to do this in `another_file.html` to create that link:

```html
<a href="../folder1/index.html">Home Page</a>
```

The `../` allows you to access the folder above your current location, which is `folder2`