# How to avoid www and non-www problems?

Tags: javascript, php, cross-domain

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    $("#citynm1").autocomplete("http://www.mywebsite.com/getcity.php", {
        width: 160,
        autoFill: false,
        selectFirst: false
    });
});     

</script>
```

This script is working when site URL start with WWW but if WWW is not available this script is not working. So what can I do?

Comment: Have you verified you have mywebsite.com pointing to your web server in DNS and your web server configured to accept requests from mywebsite.com and not just www.mywebsite.com?

Comment: Problem is with your server not script,  check dns configs, virtual host configuration on server

Comment: @DanSherwin: could be Same Origin policy violation. Try using relative web addresses, try fetching the base URL from `location`, try changing domain...

Comment: Try using a [root-relative path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559578/having-links-relative-to-root): `"/getcity.php"`. The request use the current hostname, regardless of which it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        var url="http://www.mywebsite.com/getcity.php"
         urlExists(url,function(exist){
               if(!exist){
                    url="http://mywebsite.com/getcity.php"   
               }
               urlExists(url,function(exist2){
                 if(exist2){
                   $("#citynm1").autocomplete(url,{
                       width: 160,
                       autoFill: false,
                       selectFirst: false
                     })  
                  }

               });

         }); 



    });     

    </script>
```

Known that :

```
function urlExists(url, callback){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'HEAD',
    url: url,
    success: function(){
      callback(true);
    },
    error: function() {
      callback(false);
    }
  });
}
```