# Materialize CSS simple installation

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, materialize

I am trying to install Materialize CSS, it looks pretty cool.

I installed it as per (simple) instructions, however non of the tags are working, so I assume it is an installation issue.

Below are snippets of code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css" type="text/css"  media="screen,projection"/>
</head>
```

and at the bottom of the HTML script:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

I'm just testing it with a simple card:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 m5">
        <div class="card-panel teal">
          <span class="white-text">I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
      I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively. I am similar to what is called a panel in other frameworks.
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div
```

however all that appears is text across the website, and no card.

Below is a screenshot of the files I have uploaded:

[image: FTP files]

and finally, here is the website URL! [www.econengines.com](http://econengines.com) . As you can probably tell, the site is going through a lot of development, and is kinda messy right now. I'm just tryna get a navbar going, which isn't working either.

***How can I get Materialize CSS to materialise?***

Comment: Assuming the HTML code you pasted above is in `home.html`, all of the resources (except `cgi-bin`) are in the same directory. So you should adjust your URI to the CSS and JS files accordingly.

Comment: the code above is in 'index.html'. what would I need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the HTML file is in the same location as your CSS and JS resources, you should change the locations as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="materialize.min.js"></script>
```

and

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css" type="text/css"  media="screen,projection"/>
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="materialize.min.css" type="text/css"  media="screen,projection"/>
```

More details on [having links relative to root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559578/having-links-relative-to-root).