# CSS files not found in ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I created a Content folder in wwwroot, because I read that client side things like stylesheets and scripts should be added there in the doc,  but when I add to a View I have and build the project it does not find the files. What is the correct way to do this ?

```
<link href="~/content/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I am pretty sure the wwwroot is added to project.json correctly.

```
"webroot": "wwwroot"
```

Comment: did you check case sensitivity?

Comment: Yes that was the first thing I did

Comment: @Arvaan URL's to static files are not case sensitive.

Comment: ok. it was first thought came into my mind

Comment: Did you try removing the tilde symbol? Check out this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/5559597/1454538

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to enable ASP.NET Core static files handling in your Startup:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder application)
{
    // Add static files to the request pipeline.
    application.UseStaticFiles();

    // Add MVC to the request pipeline.
    application.UseMvc();
}
```

### Visual Studio 2017 (csproj)

You also need to add this to your csproj unless you are using the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` package:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.0.0" />
```

### Visual Studio 2015 (xproj + project.json)

You also need to add this to your project.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0"
    // ...Omitted
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error that IApplicationBuilder does not contain a definition for UseStaticFiles.

Comment: You also need to add a dependency in your project.json. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The tilde (`"~"`) symbol translates to base url, but that happens in server code, through server controls or other server side url manipulation functions.

For client side URL, remove the tilde.