# Cannot get to root dir in HTML

Tags: html, apache2

I'm trying to get my `<img>` source to point at a file in another directory, but I'm struggling.

Currently it is:

```
<img src="../home/image.jpg">
```

When my apache2 server is in:

```
/var/www/html/mypage.html
```

I thought .. should get me there, but it doesn't work :(

Running apache2 webserver on Linux.

Edit:
I also tried `../../../home/user/image.jpg`, as I believe this should take me back 3 directories?

Comment: Add a symlink from your user directory to a directory inside your html folder and point there. You are trying to point directly to a file that is outside the document folder for Apache (and this is not a good idea at all)

Comment: I've done as suggested, but it still doesn't work. I've symlinked the user dir into /userCpy/ but I still can't access it =/

Comment: And where is userCpy?

Comment: Would you mind to show where exactly, how you call it in your page? Or I have to guess??

Comment: Sorry, fixed now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Using above as your image source path would suggest that its physical path is in "/var/www/home/image.jpg". Is this correct? I would also assume that your apache's root directory is at /var/www/html. You can try hard-coding the actual and complete physical path of your image for tracing purposes, but it's not going to a good practice. Finally, you can trace it in your apache logs as to what actual location is being accessed in your given img source path.

Comment: No, the path is /home/user, whereas the html is in /var/www/html

Comment: So the complete actual path of the image is at /home/user/image.jpg? You can use "../../../home/user/image.jpg", but it's shorter to hard-code the actual path instead. Alternately, I would suggest to create a symbolic link at your /var/www/html that works like a shortcut to your /home/user directory. For example, in your var/www/html directory, create a symbolic folder named images pointing to /home/user. With your image source now, you can simply access it using <img src = "images/image.jpg".

Answer (score 0):

Any path which start with "/" is relative to root for more details click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559578/having-links-relative-to-root). if your image is in "home" directory and "www" is your root directory then you can use

```
"/home/image.jpg"
```

If your image is in a directory which is not in root directory of server you can't access it from outside. I think you have placed image in wrong directory your image must should be with in apache root directory. If a client can access all files from server then your server is naked to hackers they can steel any kind of information they want!

Answer (score 0):

I used mount to get one folder appear in the web server folder tree. Not sure, but I think mounting file is also possible.

sudo mount -o bind /sourcefolderurl /destinationfolderurl

Web server to traverse all the folders up to root and then to another folder would be really bad idea. Some web servers create limited permissions user that can't escape the www folder.

Comment: This does NOT work. Just got rid of my entire html dir and replaced it with the other one!

Comment: I mean - mount /home/userX/SomeSubDir as /var/www/html/RemountedSubDir. As far as I remember symlink did not work for me and you also have to change/check the permissions (if not changed already) to free for everyone to read or check the "server user" permissions. I think mounting sub dir in sub dir is best, because if not persistent, you can loose lot of functionality after reboot.