# How to deal with paths in CSS when including the same css file from multiple directories

Tags: php, html, css, path

I have the following folder structure

```
website 
    \styles\ 
         main.css
    \directory\
         page.php  
    \layout\ 
         background.jpg 
         common_includes.php 
    index.php
```

main.css contains background-image such as

```
 #container  {
    background-image: url('../layout/background.jpg'); 
 }
```

common_includes.php contains CSS and JS files which are common to all pages.Eg:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/other.css" />
 ...
```

index.php

```
  <?php include_once '/layout/common_includes.php'; ?>
```

Everything perfect until here.

Now I want to have a folder with other pages (`/directory/page.php`).

I want `page.php` to use the same `common_includes.php`.

Obviously by doing:

```
  <?php include_once '../layout/common_includes.php'; ?>
```

doesn't work due to a different Working Directory.

I tried duplicating common_includes.php to have correct paths:

common_includes_directory.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/other.css" />
...
```

THen I got into the problem that the background.jpg in the CSS cannot be found.

How can I achieve this without having to duplicate everything?

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute path(relative to root)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/other.css" />
```

In css use

```
#container  {
    background-image: url('/layout/background.jpg'); 
 }
```

Any path which starts with "/" is relative to root and it remains same wherever you use it.
For more details read [Having links relative to root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559578/having-links-relative-to-root)

Comment: open page in chrome then open console to check which link is not working. It may have 404 error. inspect it and show results so I could help you accordingly.