# Issue with using Jquery to append a link with a relative path

Tags: jquery

Sorry for this very basic question and this is my first time posting. 
I am trying to link the following jquery to each html page in a project:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".class").append("<p><a href='../../homepage.htm'>Home page</a></p>");
});
```

The jquery is stored in a separate folder so I just reference it from each HTML page. However, the HTML pages are stored in folders in a directory type structure so does the path `../..homepage.htm` need to be different depending on where the HTML page is located in relation to `homepage.htm`?

If so, do I need a separate jquery to handle different relative paths? I suppose I could use the absolute path of homepage.htm but its location would need to be updated for each version of the project.

thanks for any help

Comment: Sorry, "apped" in the title should have been "append". Not sure how I edit the title.

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing this JS into various HTML files across the site and those files have varying sub-directory structures, then hard-coding a relative path is not possible.  You want to either hard code an absolute path or create some JS to figure out the appropriate path before appending it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a root-relative URL that starts with a `/` character. It should look something like `<a href="/directoryInRoot/fileName.html">link text</a>.`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".class" ).append( "<p><a href='/directoryInRoot/homepage.htm'>Home page</a></p>" ); 
});
```

Here is a more in-depth explanation: [Having links relative to root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559578/having-links-relative-to-root)