# Wordpress script not loading

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am having a wordpress website and some custom javascript. However my goal is to load this javascript file the right away as wordpress is suggesting it. Somehow this is not working or I am doing something wrong.
The file is called `FormScript.js` and is located here:

```
/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/Avada/FormScript.js
```

In the same directory is my function.php, in which I want to load the script.

This is how I am doing it:

```
if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
function my_jquery_enqueue() {

    // Register and Enqueue a Script
    // get_stylesheet_directory_uri will look up child theme location
    wp_register_script( 'FormScript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'FormScript.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'FormScript' );
}
```

But why is this not working? Thanks for help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `/` after `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` inside `wp_register_script`.
It should be:

```
wp_register_script( 'FormScript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/FormScript.js');
```

Edit:
From the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri):

> Note: Does not contain a trailing slash.

Comment: This isn't true anyway because when I add '/' at the beginning it will go to the root directory

Comment: No its not, its actually not at the beginning of the path. Have you checked your browser console? What path is it outputting?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559578/having-links-relative-to-root why is this saying that '/' will go to the root?

Comment: Actually its not. It depends where you place your `/` and you should read it more precise and understand it, not just copying code.
[Here is the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).

Comment: Yeah, Google is always right. I would recommend to you to read the whole  answer and not the first lines.

Comment: Okay the file is loaded now... still don't get it why. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124128/discussion-between-code-spirit-and-anokrize).

Comment: Somehow it doesn't hide the elements which I did with jQuery. Any idea why? jQuer is loaded successfully though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39682085/wordpress-external-script-not-working see this please.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you open the `header.php` file and use a simple script tag to load the `FormScript.js` file?

```
/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/Avada/FormScript.js

/httpdocs/js/FormScript.js

http://www.domain.com/js/FormScript.js
```

make sure your js file is world accessible

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/js/FormScript.js"></script>
```