# Wordpress external script not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am using this function in order to load jQuery and my custom script:

**function.php**

```
if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js", false, null);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

    // Register and Enqueue a Script
    // get_stylesheet_directory_uri will look up child theme location
    wp_register_script( 'FormScript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/FormScript.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'FormScript' );
}
```

This is a snippet of my custom script:

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  
    // jQuery is not loaded
    alert("false");
} else {
    // jQuery is loaded
    alert("true");
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#Main").hide();
    $("#Angehoerigkeit").hide();
    $("#Alter").hide();
    $("#Image").hide();

    ...
}
```

These div's are only located on one site in wordpress.
The jQuery is loaded successfully but the div's aren't hiding. Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you shouldn't be deregistering jQuery, or loading it, you should just add is a dependency for your script, and Wordpress will take care of the rest

```
if (!is_admin()) {
    add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
}

function my_jquery_enqueue() {
    wp_register_script( 'FormScript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/FormScript.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script( 'FormScript' );
}
```

secondly, jQuery runs in noConflict mode in Wordpress

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $("#Main").hide();
    $("#Angehoerigkeit").hide();
    $("#Alter").hide();
    $("#Image").hide();

});
```