# Using react-router with Express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I have a React app that is being served by a simple Express server. The React app is being `webpack`'d into a directory called `dist` in my root directory (where the `server.js` file is located as well). The dist folder includes the `index.html` entry point, `main.min.js` JavaScript bundle, and all other static assets (css, images, etc).

If I visit the root directory of the site, `localhost:3000/` for example, the `index.html` gets served, it loads the JS bundle and finds all other assets fine. The app, using `react-router`, navigates fine through button clicks and a link that brings me to `localhost:3000/feature` works fine.

However, if I manually go into the address bar and type in `localhost:3000/feature`, the server gives the `index.html` as expected, but also serves `index.html` in place of `main.min.js`. This is because the wildcard route in the express server is mapped to return `index.html`. This is how I've seen it done in some articles, but I'm not sure if this case has been considered.

Here's a snippet of the relevant server code:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname)));
app.get('*', function response(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'));
});
```

This is what defines the server routing. Is there a better way to do this that will allow manual address changes?

Here's my file structure if it helps:

```
|-root
  |-server.js
  |-webpack.config.js
  |-dist/
    |-main.min.js
    |-index.html
    |-a2cea76fae187add3c974dcacf446eab.jpg
    |-...etc
```

Contents of `index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"><!-- React app --></div>
    <script src="dist/main-631cea2c7e308b1dfb26.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: probably you need [this](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ServerRendering.md)

Comment: @IslamIbakaev is this the only solution? I'd like to avoid server-side rendering (for now) if I can.

Comment: i don't know other solutions where i want express match routes i set with react-router without actually doing "server-side react"

Comment: but if there is other solution it would be very strange that i even have not heard about it...

Comment: Can you add the content of `index.html`? The inconsistency serving the minified js file is a bit weird.

Comment: @Vier added. The name of the bundle file gets injected during webpack build by HtmlWebpackPlugin.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're referencing your script using a relative path.

For example when on `http://localhost:3000/feature` the browser will resolve the script to `http://localhost:3000/feature/dist/main-631cea2c7e308b1dfb26.min.js` which of course doesn't exist, hence the `express.static` middleware is letting the request fall through to the next middleware.

You therefore need to define it as a [root relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559578/having-links-relative-to-root) path, e.g.

```
<script src="/dist/main-631cea2c7e308b1dfb26.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Alan Thomas -- Additionally you probably should avoid serving `__dirname` with `express.static` otherwise the server code and webpack config will be accessible from a browser -- you might be better off serving `path.join(__dirname, 'dist')` and changing your script reference to just `/main-631cea2c7e308b1dfb26.min.js`.

Comment: Relative path is the issue. If you're using webpack, you can use the HtmlWebpackPlugin to inject the chunk script tag into you html file.  This will set the explicit path by default
`plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'views/index.html',
      inject: 'body',
      filename: 'index.html'
    })
  ]`

Comment: @riscarrott Referencing the script using a relative path seems to work though. I've made a basic app to test this. https://react-express-alanqthomas.c9users.io/. Source: https://ide.c9.io/alanqthomas/react-express. This is using relative pathing and works as intended.

Comment: @riscarrott might have to login and run it yourself - it should be public. I think the VM spins down after a few minutes of inactivity.