# How to change a requested url in spring mvc, before going to controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, filter, interceptor, path-variables

I am developing a web app using Spring mvc. I have page which displays all projects in DB. If i click on any of the projects listed, it will display some other additional details of that particular project. This is done by using @PathVariable.

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/project/{name}"})
public String viewProject(HttpServletRequest request,@PathVariable("name")     
String projectName, ModelMap model){
     .......
     .......

 }
```

Above is my request mapping code. My url will be http://localhost:8083/releaseDashboard/project/CSOB.html (csob is my project name and releaseDashboard is my app name). Till this my app works fine. When i click on the home button from this page, my request is mapped to the above controller method and my url becomes localhost:8083/releaseDashboard/project/home.html. But the expected url is localhost:8083/releaseDashboard/home.html

Can anyone please help me? I read that we can use Interceptor or Filters to change the requested url. But i couldnt see any code snippet for that.

**UPDATE**

***Web.xml***

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

***spring-servlet.xml***

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.suntec.reldashboard.controller" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.suntec.reldashboard.service" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.suntec.reldashboard.dao" />   
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />  
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />  
    </bean>
```

Comment: Understood what do you want. But not clear what is your error and what you have done. Why the link has a `.html`? As it is Spring MVC, it must be `http://localhost:8083/releaseDashboard/project/CSOB`.

Comment: web.xml is configured like that. That is not an issue here. if i remove that html from web.xml, my url will be the same as you mentioned in your comments.

Comment: Please edit your question with your config files - web.xml, spring config file etc. How you configured the view resolver?

Comment: @RamanujanR updated my question. Pls see

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your config in `web.xml` in the context of Spring MVC is incorrect.
Edit it as `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`. By this, all the requests to your project will pass through the 'dispatcher servlet'.

(You can also use like this `<url-pattern>something-here</url-pattern>`. Then your base url should have an extra 'something-here').

Now you can access the resource,

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/project/{name}"})
public String viewProject(HttpServletRequest request,@PathVariable("name")     
String projectName, ModelMap model){
     .......
     .......
    return "hello";
}
```

by the URL `http://localhost:8083/releaseDashboard/project/CSOB`. Then `projectName` will be **CSOB**.

You must have a 'jsp' file under `/WEB-INF/jsp/` having the name `hello.jsp`. In that jsp file, you can access `model` values.

You must not use `.html`/`.jsp` within the URL, when using Spring MVC. All the resource is bounded to a VIEW, using view resolver. That is how this must be implemented. That's for it is 'MVC' and 'view-resolving'.

**NOTE:**

As per your current configuration, "you have to change a requested URL". NO, you can't. Then your URL may be `http://localhost:8083/releaseDashboard/project/CSOB.html`; and `projectName` is "CSOB.html". Then you have to use java `substring` function to extract "CSOB" from "CSOB.html". And this is an ugly stuff!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So if i go to this url http://localhost:8083/releaseDashboard/project/CSOB it will show the contents of hello.jsp. Thats fine. But from this url, when i click on my home, it shows the url as http://localhost:8083/releaseDashboard/project/home and being mapped to the same controller method instead mapping it to a controller method with @RequestMapping(value={"home"})

Comment: "when i click on my home". Change url on that button. Obviously you are using a relative url. Make it right. Refer this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559578/having-links-relative-to-root

Comment: Currently my action on home button is "home". Then what should be my url?

Comment: `/home` i think. Or `/releaseDashboard/home`. Not sure. Check both and comment result

Comment: /home works fine. /releaseDashboard/home gives url as http://localhost:8083/releaseDashboard/releaseDashboard/home. Another thing that worked is action="../home"

Comment: Dont use `../home`,as it depends on current page `/home` is good.

Comment: but what will happen if i have another url like this,  localhost:8083/releaseDashboard/project/CSOB/52 , and i click on home from this page? From my understandings, if i give /home in action , my url will be localhost:8083/releaseDashboard/project/home. Correct? Then again my first issue will come.

Comment: NO. `/home` makes the url root relative. So it will be `localhost:8083/releaseDashboard/home` from anywhere. More info : check SO link in above comment.