# .htaccess Redirect url to folder

Tags: .htaccess

I have a blog folder in my servers `/home/app/sites` directory, and I have my laravel app in `/home/app/public_html/laravel` and my domain `www.laravelapp.com` is pointing to the project.

I want to point the url `www.laravelapp.com/blog` to my blog folder in `/home/app/sites/blog`.

How can I do that?

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect blog folder (Not working)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.laravelapp.com/blog$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/app/sites/blog [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you have access to Apache server config?

Answer (score 0):

`../` goes one folder down

So it should be ../../sites/blog

There may be restrictions with htaccess. If this not already work share your .htaccess file. You cant go behind your base url, the following question explains it very well.

[Having links relative to root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559578/having-links-relative-to-root)