# How I can write a php code inside a jQuery function in main.js file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Maybe for someone it's easy to do, but I can not write well this code:

```
$("<div id='conferm'></div>")
  .appendTo("#contact")
  .html("<span>Your products is Add!<br>check your cart <a href='<?= $config->urls->root ?>cart'>here</a> or keep to shopping</span>")
```

The problem is the link not work, because the php `$config->urls->root`  doesn't print the URL but just print it like a text.

If I add this code inside my php page works well, but inside a js file not works.

How I can write it for let the link work well?

Thank you!

Comment: You can't as PHP isn't interpreted within a file with a .js extension. If you want to get the PHP value, write it to the page somewhere, as a `data` attribute on the `body` for example, then read that out in your JS file

Comment: You would have to do an inline script within a PHP file, and then execute the PHP inside that.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I wrote an answer not knowing you gave hints about the problem already, I'll leave it, it might be useful :)

Comment: instead of using php, javascript's `window.location.host` gives root url and `window.location.protocol` gives protocol (http or https) you can use that if needed

Comment: or this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559578/having-links-relative-to-root#5559597

Comment: Thank you @RoryMcCrossan, I suspected it was so. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
     echo '<script> var rooturl = ' . $config->urls->root . ';</script>' 
?>
```

And then change this to:

```
$("<div id='conferm'></div>")
      .appendTo("#contact")
      .html("<span>Your products is Add!<br>check your cart <a href='" +rooturl+ "cart'>here</a> or keep to shopping</span>");
```

Take into consideration the load order so that your JS file knows your `rooturl` variable. Your `PHP` must print the `echo` code on your `html` document before you process it on your `JS` file.

Comment: However since we don't know what else is in his .js file (like a document.ready possibly), this may not work if the .js include is before the echo'd script block in the html. So care is to be taken with this method about 'load order'.

Comment: You are absolutely right @IncredibleHat. I guess he might be aware of that but yah.. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks @animake and IncredibleHat this work so well!! Yes sure, I have add the main.js in the footer. Thank you Again!!

Answer (score 0):

You can not write PHP code in .js files, because they are made for javascript only.
But, you could do the following:

Make ajax function in your .js file, that will get you proper value for your href attribute

```js
var link_href = "";
$.ajax({
  data: "",
  url: "my_php_file.php",
  type: "GET",
  success: function(data){
   link_href = data;
    //data is what your .php file echos
    //in your example you want to make sure your php files echos only href attribute you need for your <a> tag
  }
});
var a = document.getElementById("a_link");
a.setAttribute("href", link_href);
```

Comment: This won't work as the AJAX request is asynchronous.

Comment: ... and `async: false` isn't a solution to that :)