# How do I link to a file that is in the parent folder?

Tags: html, filepath

```
Website
    Home.html
    Pages
        Page1.html
```

Above is a file tree that I'm trying to navigate. How can I reference Home.html from Page1.html?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Having links relative to root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559578/having-links-relative-to-root)

Answer (score 0):

Prefacing a URI with `../` ( e.g. `<a href="../Home.html">Home</a>` ) will move up the tree by one folder (repeat as necessary). 
Prefacing a URI with `/` ( e.g. `<a href="/Home.html">Home</a>` ) will move to the tree's root.