# PWA Service Worker (Workbox) setting's '/' stand for?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I want to create PWA's service worker file by using workbox.
According to workbox document, precaching setting of workbox is something like this:

**service-worker.js**

```
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([
  '/styles/example.ac29.css',
  { url: '/index.html', revision: 'abcd1234' },
  // ... other entries ...
]);
```

But what is the actual meaning of `/index.html` or `/styles/example.ac29.css`?
It is server root? or, the root of PWA's scope?

For example, if `service-worker.js` is served in **`https://example.com/hoge/fuga/service-worker.js`**, and `manifest.json` is also served in **`https://example.com/hoge/fuga/manifest.json`** with content:

```
{
  "name": "Great PWA site",
  "background_color": "#f6f0d3",
  "icons": [...],
  "start_url": "https://example.com/hoge/fuga/",
  "scope":"/hoge/fuga/",
  "display": "standalone"
}
```

In such case, `/index.html` in workbox setting means **`https://example.com/index.html`**? Or, **`https://example.com/hoge/fuga/index.html`**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within Workbox's precache manifest, `/index.html` is resolved to a full URL using the server root as the base. It does not user the service worker scope as the base. (After Googling, I guess it's technically called a ["root-relative" URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559578/having-links-relative-to-root), though I've never really used that phrase before.)

If you had a relative URL like `./index.html`, it would be resolved to a full URL using the location of the service worker script as the base.

In general, if you're curious as to what a URL will resolve to, you can run the following from the `ServiceWorkerGlobalScope` to see:

```
(new URL('some-URL.html', self.location.href)).href
```

The easiest way to do this is to open up Chrome's DevTools while on a page you're curious about that has a service worker, go to the Console panel, and choose the service worker's scope in the popup menu, and then enter the code above.

[image]