# CRUD JDBC template problem with edit operation

Tags: spring-mvc, crud, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate, insert-update

I have problem with CRUD edit operation. When i click Edit which is written in this way in jsp file

```
 <a href="editMedicines?id=${medicines.id}">Edit</a>
```

i got error

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report
Message /Firstaidkit/editMedicines
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

EditController

```
@WebServlet(value = "/editMedicines")
    public class MedicinesEditController extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editMedicines(HttpServletRequest request) {
        int medicinesId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        Medicines medicines = GenericDAO.get(medicinesId);
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("editform");
        model.addObject("medicines", medicines);
        return model;
    }
}
```

GenericDAO

```
public interface GenericDAO <T, PK extends Serializable> {
    //CRUD
    T create(T newObject);
    T read(PK primaryKey);
    public void update(Medicines medicines);
    public void delete(T id);
    List<T> getAll();
    public static Medicines get(int medicinesId) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

MedicinesDAOImpl

```
 private final static String UPDATE_MEDICINES = 
          "UPDATE medicines SET name=:name, drugform=:drugform, quantity=:quantity, expiration_date=:expiration_date, description=:description WHERE id_medicines=:id_medicines;";

        @Override
        public void update(Medicines medicines) {
                jdbcTemplate.update(UPDATE_MEDICINES, medicines.getName(), medicines.getDrugForm(),
                        medicines.getQuantity(), medicines.getExpirationDate(), medicines.getId());
            } 
        }
```

editform.jsp

```
<form class="form-signin" method="post" action="editMedicines">
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that the URL your anchor is linked to does not exist.  You should have an annotation dictating the path on your `MedicinesEditController` at a class level. Assuming you want the path of this endpoint to be `/Firstaidkit/editMedicines`, the following should work:

```java
@Path(value = "/Firstaidkit") // possibly a different but similar annotation
public class MedicinesEditController extends HttpServlet {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/editMedicines", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editMedicines(HttpServletRequest request) {
        int medicinesId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        Medicines medicines = GenericDAO.get(medicinesId);
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("editform");
        model.addObject("medicines", medicines);
        return model;
    }

}
```

Otherwise, you need to alter the link of the anchor to reference the root of the application, followed by your endpoint of `/editMedicines`. This can be accomplished by using the following anchor, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5559597/12794752):

`<a href="/editMedicines?id=${medicines.id}">Edit</a>`

**Edit: Try the following**

MedicinesEditController

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editMedicines")
    public class MedicinesEditController extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView editMedicines(HttpServletRequest request) {
        int medicinesId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        Medicines medicines = GenericDAO.get(medicinesId);
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("editform");
        model.addObject("medicines", medicines);
        return model;
    }
}
```

editform.jsp

```
<form class="form-signin" method="GET" action="editMedicines">
```

anchor

(note: try these variations, as the link changes depending on where you are when you click it. View [this stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559578/having-links-relative-to-root/5559597) to help determine the correct link)

```
 <a href="editMedicines?id=${medicines.id}">Edit</a>
 <a href="/editMedicines?id=${medicines.id}">Edit</a>
 <a href="../editMedicines?id=${medicines.id}">Edit</a>
```

Comment: First post edited.
I have added `@WebServlet(value = "/editMedicines")` but now got new error:                                                                                   
  
`HTTP Status 405 – Method Not Allowed
Type Status Report

Message HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

Description The method received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not supported by the target resource.`

or if i use form with POST to edit i got same error but this line is different `Message HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL`

Comment: What is the url you are trying to hit? Also, is the form action in your JSP still a `POST`?

Comment: Firstaidkit/editMedicines?id=1
Yes it is still `POST` as you see on the first post

Comment: with your tips i got previous error `HTTP Status 404 – Not Found`. Im using same url like 2 comments up

Comment: @Pabblo96 I am looking at code which is very similar to what you are doing, and it is working. Maybe you don't need the `<form>` on your JSP and that is causing issues? Otherwise the issue is likely the link in the `<a>` tag. I would use Devtools to add a button to the page and play around with different combinations of paths (add a `/`, add `../`, add the full path of your URL) until you get the desired behavior.

Comment: Okay I will try something tomorrow because im done today, thank you for help!