# Why CSS file not working in my application?

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

I'm trying to use `.css` files in my project but it doesn't work. The directory hierarchy is: `/resources/static/css/style.css`. In my html file I tried

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Header</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href = "/css/style.css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}" >
</head>
```

but it does not work. What to do to make the style work? I read several articles but did not understand how to solve the problem

Comment: Where is the HTML file in that structure? Do you get any console errors?

Answer (score 0):

When using `/` at the start of your href address you are addressing from the root. so you should change the CSS link to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href = "/resources/static/css/style.css"  />
```

or just link it relatively with `./`

for more information read this :

[having-links-relative-to-root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559578/having-links-relative-to-root)

Answer (score 0):

try to add type="text/css" 
and adding dot to href="./your/location/style.css"

Comment: Type is not needed with HTML5.