# how to properly link source in html inside folders?

Tags: html, href, filepath, src

i have multiple folders with other htmls, i want to link them all between each other.

folder structure looks like this:

```
Main Folder
   index.html
   nav.js
   Project Folder
      project1.html
      project2.html
   images
      image1.png
      image2.png
```

this is how i try to link:

1. index.html:  `<a href="/Project Folder/project1.html"></a> <a href="./Project Folder/project1.html"></a>`
2. project1.html: `<a href="/index.html"></a> <img src="./images/image1.png> <script src="./nav.js">`

it works with visual code live, but doesn't work when i open just index.html.
i get error for not loading neither image or script, and when i press on a i get another error of page not found.

i want to figure out what is proper way of linking items inside multiple folders and in which case i have to use "./" or "/" and if there is anything else.

Comment: **root-relative-paths** start with a `/` and that is what you actually need in your case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Having links relative to root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559578/having-links-relative-to-root)

Comment: Have all your links start with a `/` instead of `./` not just the index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start a URL with "/", it goes to the very beginning (root) of the path.

When using VSCode Live Server, it runs a local server which has a root path of the directory you have open in VSCode. With live server, you will have a URL like `localhost:5000/index.html`. As the root path is in the same location where the index.html is located, you can just type `/index.html` to access it.

When you manually open the index.html, the root directory changes to the root of the drive you have the file located in (e.g. C:). If you open the file manually, your web browser is opening something like `C:/Users/User/Desktop/Website/index.html`. If you were to try access `/index.html`, it would then go to `C:/index.html` on your hard drive.

If you are trying to access a file that is in the same directory as the current html file you have open, you want to remove the `/` from the beginning of the URL.

If you are wanting to access a file that is accessible from the parent directory, you want to have it start as `../`

To make what you currently have work when you directly open the .html file, make the following changes:

index.html

Before: `<a href="/Project Folder/project1.html"></a>`

After: `<a href="Project Folder/project1.html"></a>`

project1.html

Before: `<a href="/index.html"></a> <img src="./images/image1.png"> <script src="./nav.js">`

After: `<a href="../index.html"></a> <img src="../images/image1.png"> <script src="../nav.js">`