# How to get the jpg from this url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

This API provides thumbnails from websites.

```
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://webthumb.bluga.net/easythumb.php?user=00000&url=www.consumerreports.com&hash=sdf9g879d8f7g9sd8fg7s9df&size=medium&cache=30">
```

The user id and hash value have been redacted, but if they were right, this tag would result in a small thumbnail on your page called `easythumb.jpeg`.

Is there any way to grab that thumbnail and store it either in my DB or in AWS?

Or was webthumb carefully designed to prevent such behavior?

Edit:

Tried Nokogiri per the suggestion below, and here is the return. It looks like there's no way to get a jpg out of this. Am I right?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074309/how-do-i-download-a-picture-using-ruby

Comment: nah - that question has a jpg in the url - mine doesn't.

Comment: Ahh. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926675/save-all-image-files-from-a-website -- The top answer suggests using Nokogiri, which I've also used for scraping/downloading

Comment: Did you select the `img` tags? Something like this: (from the linked answer) `Nokogiri::HTML(open(URL)).xpath("//img/@src").each do |src|
  uri = URI.join( URL, src ).to_s # make absolute uri
  File.open(File.basename(uri),'wb'){ |f| f.write(open(uri).read) }
end`

Comment: I didn't because I didn't see "img" anywhere in that mass of text that was returned to me. Also don't know what that 'xpath' does. Is that the secret sauce which will get my jpeg? Guess I'll start reading up on nokogiri!

Comment: Well, `img` simply looks for any image tags in the HTML. Not sure if you would see that in the Nokogiri output. Xpath is simply a way to traverse the DOM -- nothing too magical. Good luck!

Comment: That "mass of text" is probably your image. You need to save it.

Comment: We need to see source code showing what you're trying. As is you're asking us to image it. As is this isn't a complete question. Nokogiri parses HTML, it doesn't retrieve anything. OpenURI does that for your code, and is all that is necessary to retrieve an image, after which you can save the returned content to a file.

Comment: Also, don't use screen shots to show us important text. Screen shots are not easy to read, nor is the text in it easily reused if we need to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to understand what things do what. Here's some code, which has been tested to the point of downloading the image:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

html = '<img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://webthumb.bluga.net/easythumb.php?user=00000&url=www.consumerreports.com&hash=sdf9g879d8f7g9sd8fg7s9df&size=medium&cache=30">'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

uri = URI.parse(doc.at('img')['src']) 
# => #<URI::HTTP:0x007f8e13258520 URL:http://webthumb.bluga.net/easythumb.php?user=00000&url=www.consumerreports.com&hash=sdf9g879d8f7g9sd8fg7s9df&size=medium&cache=30>

File.basename(uri.path) 
# => "easythumb.php"

File.open(File.basename("#{ uri.path }.jpeg"), 'wb') { |fo| fo.write(open(uri).read) }
```

That all said, the URL isn't valid. Opening a browser page and pasting in that URL returns "Bad Hash", not an image.