# How can I click on a specific link with Nokogori or Mechanize?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, bots, mechanize, open-uri

I know how to find an element using Nokogiri. I know how to click a link using Mechanize. But I can't figure out how to find a specific link and click it. This seems like it should be really easy, but for some reason I can't find a solution.

Let's say I'm just trying to click on the first result on a Google search. I can't just click the first link with Mechanize, because the Google page has a bunch of other links, like Settings. The search result links themselves don't seem to have class names, but they're enveloped in `<h3 class="r"></h3>`.

I could just use Nokogiri to follow the `href` value of the link like so:

```
document = open("https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow")
parsed_content = Nokogiri::HTML(document.read)
href = parsed_content.css('.r').children.first['href']
new_document = open(href)
# href is equal to "/url?sa=t&amp;rct=j&amp;q=&amp;esrc=s&amp;source=web&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F"
```

but it's not a direct url, and going to that url gives an error. The `data-href` value is a direct url, but I can't figure out how to get that value - doing the same thing except with `...first['data-href']` returns nil.

**Anyone know how I can just find the first `.r` element on the page and click the link inside it?**

Here's the start to my action:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'mechanize'
document = open("https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow")
parsed_content = Nokogiri::HTML(document.read)
```

Here's the `.r` element on the Google search results page:

```
<h3 class="r">
  <a href="/url?sa=t&amp;rct=j&amp;q=&amp;esrc=s&amp;source=web&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F" data-href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Stack Overflow</a>
</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure your question is the correct code in your example - it looks like it is not, because you don't surround the url in quotes and the css selector is `.r a` not `r`.  You use `.r a` because you want to access the link inside elements with the `r` class.

Anyway, you can use the approach detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861517/how-can-i-get-the-absolute-url-when-extracting-links-using-nokogiri) like so:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'uri'

base_url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow"
document = open(base_url)
parsed_content = Nokogiri::HTML(document.read)
href = parsed_content.css('.r').first.children.first['href']
new_url = URI.join base_url, href
new_document = open(new_url)
```

I tested this and following `new_url` does redirect to StackOverflow as expected.

Comment: Good catch, I typed instead of copy + paste. This is weird though, this exact code doesn't work for me, but using `('.r').first.children.first['href']` and just `href` instead of  `href.value`, does.

Comment: @JosefKrazinsky you're right, must have made an error copy-pasting myself